# can't update any packages due to error in '/usr/sbin/update-info-dir'

Tags: apt, bash

I'm unable to update any packages in ubuntu due to an error in '/usr/sbin/update-info-dir'

the error is given as:

```
Setting up install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 9: export: : bad variable name
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):..........]
 installed install-info package post-installation script subprocess returned err
or exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Which seems to suggest the problem is on line '9'. The first nine lines are as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
# update-info-dir
# create a dir file from all installed info files
# Copyright 2009, 2014 Norbert Preining
# GPLv2

INFODIR=/usr/share/info

set -e
```

I've seen similar problems on the stack but they weren't exactly the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `/usr/sbin/update-info-dir` sources both `/etc/environment` and `/etc/default/locale` - I wonder if the error is in line 9 of one of those files?

Comment: That was it! Thank you, it was an erroneous space in a 'set' command in the /etc/environment file. Perhaps 'set' ought to be a bit more forgiving, stripping spaces (although I should imagine 'fixing' something like that would cause half the world to break)

Comment: Hmm... glad you got it fixed but AFAIK the /etc/environment shouldn't contain any shell syntax except a list of "`KEY=VALUE`" environment variable assignments

Answer (score 2):

The `/usr/sbin/update-info-dir` sources both `/etc/environment` and `/etc/default/locale`.

Likely the error is at Line 9 of one of those files - sourcing a file confuses the line numbering in the error report. For example, given:

```
$ cat -n good.sh
     1  #!/bin/sh
     2
     3  . ./bad.environment
```

and

```
$ cat -n bad.environment
     1  # some comments
     2  #
     3  # more comments
     4  #
     5  # even more comments
     6  #
     7  #
     8
     9  export foo =bar
```

then

```
$ ./good.sh
./good.sh: 9: export: : bad variable name
```

---

Note that according to `man environment.d` (emphasis mine):

```
CONFIGURATION FORMAT
       The configuration files contain a list of "KEY=VALUE" environment
       variable assignments, separated by newlines. The right hand side of
       these assignments may reference previously defined environment
       variables, using the "${OTHER_KEY}" and "$OTHER_KEY" format. It is also
       possible to use "${FOO:-DEFAULT_VALUE}" to expand in the same way as
       "${FOO}" unless the expansion would be empty, in which case it expands
       to DEFAULT_VALUE, and use "${FOO:+ALTERNATE_VALUE}" to expand to
       ALTERNATE_VALUE as long as "${FOO}" would have expanded to a non-empty
       value. No other elements of shell syntax are supported.

       Each KEY must be a valid variable name. Empty lines and lines beginning
       with the comment character "#" are ignored.
```

so the `/etc/environment` file should not contain shell constructs such as `export` at all.